# Regular expression not working for special character

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to create a regular expression for a field with the following conditions.

1. no blank should allowed
2. special characters are not allowed apart from underscore, hyphen, period.
3. Alphabets and numeric are allowed.

I have created my own regular expression its working fine but it is accepting one special character in the beginning

1. like if i enter **@ or $wer** in the field it will work and data will be saved.
2. like if i enter **@@ , %^hihf or qwerty@333**  in the field it will show an error.

find below code.

```
$.formUtils.addValidator({
        name: "username",
        validatorFunction: function(a) {
           return !!a.match((/^[^\s][ A-Za-z0-9_./-]*$/))
        },
        errorMessage: "Please enter a valid Username (Special characters are not allowed apart from Underscore(_), Hyphen(-) and Period(.)) ",
        errorMessageKey: "badname"
    }),
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need more than just a Regex for some of these conditions. Try:

```
validatorFunction: function(a) {
    var rgx = /^[A-Za-z0-9_./-]+$/;
    var trimmed = a.trim();
    return trimmed.length > 0 && rgx.test(trimmed);
}
```

This would solve the issues of blanks, special characters, and forcing alphanumerics...

Comment: @JasshhAndrews Are you sure? I just tested this in my browser's JS console and it always returns `false` on invalid input, and `true` on valid input.

Comment: It worked. can you explain this  return trimmed.length > 0 && rgx.test(trimmed);

Comment: It's a boolean expression that verifies the following: the string is non-empty, and that the trimmed string matches the regex.

Comment: test(trimmed) - test is a default function.

Comment: What do you mean?

Answer (score 1):

Your `[^\s]` at the start of the regex means any character other than a space is valid, hence "@" will match.

I think you want to use something like this to allow leading and trailing whitespace and force at least 1 valid character:

```
return !!a.match((/^\s*[A-Za-z0-9_\./\-]+\s*$/))
```